# Send email with options in Power Apps using Office365Outlook Connector

Tags: powerapps, office365connectors

I just recently found the "Send mail with options" function in Power Apps with the **Office365Connector**. It seems to have two items that it needs to run:

```
(NotificationURL, Message)
```

I am assuming the "NotificiationURL" is the address that will receive the response, however, the "message" is saying that it needs a record.

I am not too sure where to go from here.

Any suggestions on how to use this feature?

I tried just writing a text message. It noted that it expected a record. I then tried using `{}` to formulate a message using {`to:, subject:, body:, choices:}` but it then asked for a
\ expected "Attachments" as a table. I tried adding an "Attachments:" section, but that did not work. I then tried embedding a **SendEmail(V2)** function, but that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Following is an example, of how you can use this feature:

```
Office365Outlook.SendMailWithOptions("https://www.google.ca", 
    { 
        To: "xyz@zyz.com", 
        Subject: "This Is My Options Email Title", 
        Options: "Option1,Option2,Option3", 
        HeaderText:"Header Text", 
        SelectionText: "Selection text", 
        Body: "This is the message you want to send", 
        Importance: "Low", 
        Attachments:Blank(), 
        UseOnlyHTMLMessage: true, 
        HideHTMLMessage: true, 
        HideMicrosoftFooter: true, 
        ShowHTMLConfirmationDialog: true 
    } 
)
```

Above mentioned are the minimum required attributes you must pass to send an email.

Definitions of the attributes:

- **To:** email of the person, to whom you want to send mail
- **Subject:** Subject of the mail,  Options: Options you want to send,
- **HeaderText:** Header of your selection options
- **SelectionText:** Text (question/instruction) you want to put for the options
- **Body:** Any other details you want to add other than `SelectionText`
- Importance: level of the severity of the mail
- **UseOnlyHTMLMessage:** `true` if you want to use HTML text in your body (instead of simple text)
- **HideMicrosoftFooter:** A default footer is added by the power apps/power automated if you want to remove it put the value as `false`
- **ShowHTMLConfirmationDialog:** After the user has picked an option, keeping this `true` will show them a confirmation message (screen) for their selected option